# How to add react-navigation in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I followed every steps specified in the docs.Installed the specified packages and  While trying to run the app in android-emulator, I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: (0, _stack.StackNavigator) is not a function. (In '(0, _stack.StackNavigator)()', '(0, _stack.StackNavigator)' is undefined
```

The following is content in my App.js file

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {StackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
const Stack = StackNavigator();
function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Detail Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default App;
```

The following is dependencies in my package.json file

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
        "@react-navigation/core": "^5.3.2",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.4",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.9",
        "react": "16.11.0",
        "react-native": "0.62.1",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
        "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0"
      }
```

As mentioned in the Docs, I tried placing the following code at the top of both index.js and App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing the wrong function `import {StackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';`

instead it should be

`import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';`

and

`const Stack = createStackNavigator();`

check the [get started](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) guide